# Data export permissions for custom profile

Tags: data-export

I have a custom profile. I want that profile users to able to export data using "Data Export" link under setup menu. But that link is not visible to that user. How can I make that link visible to my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help says that the profile needs the 'Data Export' permission, but unfortunately there isn't a permission with that name.  There is, however, a 'Weekly Data Export' permission - if you enable that permission for the custom profile, that will allow access to the Data Export setup option.

One point to note, from the help:

> Users with the “Data Export” permission can view all exported data and
>   all custom objects and fields in the Export Service page. This
>   permission is granted by default only to the System Administrator
>   profile because it enables wide visibility.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my license type is salesforce platform.

Comment: That would have been useful information in the question - the Weekly Data Export permission is not available to the platform user license so you can't make this functionality available to users with that license.